# Audio Zero not responding on MKR Zero

Tags: audio, arduino-zero

I have a Arduino MKR Zero set up with a sd card in it and a speaker hooked up to the ground and DAC0. I have a .wav file on it called "test.wav" and it is 8 bit mono 88200hz recording. I am using the AudioZero example to try to play this audio file off the speaker but it is not working. When I upload and run the code and open the Serial Monitor to check to see if it has any errors or sucesses reading the files it is just blank. It uploads the code all fine, but the Serial Monitor says nothing at all and the speaker doesnt play anything. Did I set it up wrong somehow?

Here is the code that it is running:

```
  Simple Audio Player for Arduino Zero

 Demonstrates the use of the Audio library for the Arduino Zero

 Hardware required :
 * Arduino shield with a SD card on CS4
 * A sound file named "test.wav" in the root directory of the SD card
 * An audio amplifier to connect to the DAC0 and ground
 * A speaker to connect to the audio amplifier


 Arturo Guadalupi <a.guadalupi@arduino.cc>
 Angelo Scialabba <a.scialabba@arduino.cc>
 Claudio Indellicati <c.indellicati@arduino.cc>

 This example code is in the public domain

 http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleAudioPlayerZero

*/

#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <AudioZero.h>

void setup()
{
  // debug output at 115200 baud
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // setup SD-card
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(SDCARD_SS_PIN)) {
    Serial.println(" failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println(" done.");
  // hi-speed SPI transfers
  SPI.setClockDivider(4);

  // 88200 sample rate
  AudioZero.begin(2*44100);
}

void loop()
{
  int count = 0;

  // open wave file from sdcard
  File myFile = SD.open("test.wav");
  if (!myFile) {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error and stop
    Serial.println("error opening test.wav");
    while (true);
  }

  Serial.print("Playing");

  // until the file is not finished  
  AudioZero.play(myFile);
  AudioZero.end();

  Serial.println("End of file. Thank you for listening!");
  while (true) ;
}
```

Comment: add `while (!Serial);` after Serial.begin to wait for Serial Monitor connection

Comment: When I do that it looks like it is initializing correctly because the serial monitor now says ``Initializing SD card... done.``   But then it just freezes on that and doesn't get any further.

Comment: try the CardInfo example of the SD library

Comment: The card info example runs just fine and gives me all the info with no errors.

Comment: did you test the speaker or buzzer with tone()?

Comment: Yes I did. The tone works just fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Serial monitor with Arduino MKRZERO, use SerialUSB instead of Serial, i.e. SerialUSB.println("something");